# Display the two columns used as a key join in join dataframe result

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have the following simple join:

```
df_join = (df1.join(df2, on=['key'], how='left').select(df1['key'], df2['key']))
```

It returns the following error `Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation`

I understand I can't display two columns with the same name but I do I do it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can give an [alias](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.alias.html) to either one of them

```
df_join = df1.join(df2, on=['key'], how='left')\
                 .select(
                   df1['key'], df2['key'].alias('right_key')
                 )
```

## Example -

```
input_str1 = """
|a|100
|b|100
|c|100
""".split("|")

input_values1 = list(map(lambda x:x.strip(),input_str1))[1:]

input_list1 = [(x,y) for x,y in zip(input_values1[0::2],input_values1[1::2])]

sparkDF1 = sql.createDataFrame(input_list1,['id','value'])

input_str2 = """
|a|20    |2020-01-02 01:30
|a|50    |2020-01-02 05:30
|b|50    |2020-01-15 07:30
|b|80    |2020-02-01 09:30
|c|50    |2020-02-01 09:30
""".split("|")

input_values2 = list(map(lambda x:x.strip(),input_str2))[1:]

input_list2 = [(x,y,z) for x,y,z in zip(input_values2[0::3],input_values2[1::3],input_values2[2::3])]

sparkDF2 = sql.createDataFrame(input_list2,['id','value','timestamp'])

finalDF = (sparkDF1.join(sparkDF2
                        ,sparkDF1['id'] == sparkDF2['id']
                        ,'inner'
                       ).select(sparkDF2["*"],sparkDF2['id'].alias('id_right')))

finalDF.show()

+---+-----+--------+
| id|value|id_right|
+---+-----+--------+
|  c|  100|       c|
|  b|  100|       b|
|  b|  100|       b|
|  a|  100|       a|
|  a|  100|       a|
+---+-----+--------+
```

Comment: I did exactly this and I have the same error... (which doesn't make sense to me...)

Comment: updated the answer , it worked perfectly fine for me